# Fit ggplot legend within plot using multiple geometries in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a ggplot figure that uses both geom_ribbon and geom_line and want both to show up in the legend.  My figure has the legend at the bottom, but it's spilling off the sides of the figure.  Is there a way to stack the legends with position="bottom" so one shows up on top of the other and they fit below the figure?

Example using iris dataset and artificial stats

```
library(tidyverse)

iris |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(
    min = Petal.Width -.5,
    mid = Petal.Width + 1.5,
    max = Petal.Width + 3.5,
    pw1 = Petal.Width +1,
    pw2 = Petal.Width + 2,
    pw3 = Petal.Width + 3
         ) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = Petal.Length))+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = Petal.Width,
                  ymax = pw3,
                  fill = "Normal Range \n(middle 80%"),
              alpha = .7)+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = pw1,
                  ymax = pw2,
                  fill = "Inner Quartile Range \n(middle 50%)"),
              alpha = .7)+
  geom_line(aes(y = max, linetype = "Maximum"))+
  geom_line(aes(y = mid, linetype = "Median"))+
  geom_line(aes(y = min, linetype = "Minimum"))+
  scale_fill_manual("Statistic",
                    values = c("lightgreen", "blue"),
                    guide = guide_legend(order = 1)) +
  scale_linetype_manual("",
                        values = c("dotted", "dashed", "dotted")
  )+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

I would like to move the legend for linetype underneath the legend for fill, and have them centered sot they don't spill out off of the plotting window.  Is there a way to do this?

I tried adding`guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 2), linetype = guide_legend(nrow = 3))` and this wrapped it, but shrank the actual plot so the legend was almost as tall as the plot itself, making the plot illegible, also I couldn't figure out how to control the order of the two geometries in the legend so the label ("Statistic") shows up on the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `legend.box = "vertical"` inside `theme` to stack the two legends, and make the linetype legend come first by putting `order = 1` inside the linetype aesthetic's `guide_legend`

```r
iris |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(
    min = Petal.Width -.5,
    mid = Petal.Width + 1.5,
    max = Petal.Width + 3.5,
    pw1 = Petal.Width +1,
    pw2 = Petal.Width + 2,
    pw3 = Petal.Width + 3
  ) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = Petal.Length))+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = Petal.Width,
                  ymax = pw3,
                  fill = "Normal Range \n(middle 80%"),
              alpha = 0.7)+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = pw1,
                  ymax = pw2,
                  fill = "Inner Quartile Range \n(middle 50%)"),
              alpha = 0.7)+
  geom_line(aes(y = max, linetype = "Maximum")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = mid, linetype = "Median")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = min, linetype = "Minimum")) +
  scale_fill_manual("Statistic",
                    values = c("lightgreen", "blue"),
                    guide = guide_legend(order = 1)) +
  scale_linetype_manual(NULL, values = c("dotted", "dashed", "dotted")) +
  guides(linetype = guide_legend(order = 1)) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.box = "vertical")
```

[image]